# How do I set false/NoCollision in the collision event in Box2D with libgdx?

Tags: android, box2d, game-physics, physics-engine, libgdx

I am developing a 2D, underwater, action-RPG for Android, using Box2D as the physics engine, mainly for collision detection, collision response and movement of in-game characters within an environment comprised of walls, rocks, and other creatures.

I am trying to implement character animations (as per [What's best way to do character animations in Box2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590959/whats-the-best-way-to-do-character-animations-with-box2d)).

The problem is that I want to suppress the collision response when a collision happens. I have been told that I should set 'NoCollision' in the collision event, which I assume you do by b2Contact::SetEnabled(false) in the Pre-Solve Event. But, the libgdx JNI implementation doesn't implement the pre-solve or post-solve methods in the interface, as it can "be done another way" [as stated here](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1657&cpage=1#comment-1511).

Does anyone have any idea how else I might do this?

I'm new to Box2D, and finding it very hard going, so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Never mind, I've updated the JNI interface to implement the pre and post solve methods, so now I can just use: contact.SetEnabled(false);

Comment: Hi Steve, can you please provide the changes you made (via pastebin or so) or maybe even directly contribute them back to libgdx? Thanks!